# Homeomorphism between two circles

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to understand how homeomorphism works and have found a result that I find somehow distant from my intuition.

Consider the functions:

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x-5 & x \in 2\mathbb{S}^1+5\\ 
 x& x \in \mathbb{S}^1 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$g(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x+5 & x \in 2\mathbb{S}^1\\ 
 x& x \in \mathbb{S}^1 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

where $f: A\rightarrow B$, $g: B\rightarrow A$, $A:= \mathbb{S}^1 \cup 2\mathbb{S}^1+5 , B:=\mathbb{S}^1 \cup 2\mathbb{S}^1$ and everything is viewed inside $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology.

By the pasting lemma they are continuous and since they are one the inverse of the other one I conclude that two concentric circles are homeomorphic to two circles with one external to the other one.

Supposed that what I said above is true I'm moving one of the circles inside the other one, and by doing so these two circle will somehow have to intersect during the transformation, which is not a behaviour I'd expect from a homeomorphism (it is imprecise but I hope to have been clear in exposing what my doubt is).

My question: have I made any mistake? If yes, how do you intuitively justify this fact?

Comment: You might like to think about whether the [trefoil knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot) and the circle are homeomorphic.

Comment: "I'm moving one of the circles inside the other one, and by doing so these two circle will somehow have to intersect during the transformation". The key word there is "during" -- there is no "during" in a homeomorphism. You should look at the concept of [homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy), which is different from homeomorphism.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC But homeomorphic spaces are also homotopic equivalent. You meant deformation retractions or I'm still missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should **NOT** think of a homeomorphism as describing a continuous transformation: it is simply a mapping showing that two objects are topologically identical. There is no motion involved. In your example the maps do not represent a movement of one circle ‘through’ the other: they just say that these two object, each consisting of two disjoint circles, are topologically indistinguishable. And they are topologically indistinguishable from any other pair of disjoint circles, no matter how they are embedded in the plane, in $\Bbb R^3$, or anywhere else.